# Msal loginRedirect does not return to home page

Tags: vue.js, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have a simple Vue SPA with a single url - `http://localhost:5174/` and msal adb2c authentication. I've replaced `loginPopup` with `loginRedirect` and faced a following issue
When I'm calling `loginRedirect`, browser moving me to the microsoft page with authentication and after I enter my credentials, it returns not to `http://localhost:5174/`, but to `http://localhost:5174/#state=eyJpZCI6...&client_info=edwdw...0&code=eyJr...` with 'This site can’t be reached' message and I see the following message in the console:

[image]

Mu msal initialization code:

```
 export interface IMsalOptions {
  clientId: string;
  loginAuthority: string;
  knownAuthority: string;
  redirectUri?: string;
}

export class MsalInitializer {
  constructor(private options: IMsalOptions) {}

  public initialize() {
    const msalConfig: Configuration = {
      auth: {
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
        clientId: this.options.clientId,
        authority: this.options.loginAuthority,
        knownAuthorities: [this.options.knownAuthority],
        redirectUri: this.options.redirectUri,
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
      },
      system: {
        loggerOptions: {
          loggerCallback: (level: LogLevel, message: string, containsPii: boolean): void => {
            if (containsPii) {
              return;
            }
            switch (level) {
              case LogLevel.Error:
                console.error(message);
                return;
              case LogLevel.Info:
                console.info(message);
                return;
              case LogLevel.Verbose:
                console.debug(message);
                return;
              case LogLevel.Warning:
                console.warn(message);
                return;
            }
          },
          piiLoggingEnabled: false,
          logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose,
        },
      },
    };

    const msal = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    msal
      .handleRedirectPromise()
      .then((loginResponse) => {
        console.log(loginResponse);
        if (loginResponse) {
          const store = useUserStore();
          store.updateUser(loginResponse);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

    return msal;
  }
}
```

My sign in function:

```
public signIn() {
    const loginRequest: RedirectRequest = {
      scopes: [...scopes.defaultScopes, scopes.apiScopes.apiRead, scopes.apiScopes.apiWrite],
    };

    msal.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
}
```

My redirect URL from the config:
`http://localhost:5174/`

And my app registration configuration from Azure:

[image]

My expectation: after successful login msal will redirect me back to `http://localhost:5174/` and I will get user's claims and token in the console.